# (webform) how can i get the value from 9 different textbox and post back the value follow by ascending

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

This is the code for webform(asp.net c#):

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int no1;
    int no2;
    int no3;
    int no4;
    int no5;
    int no6;
    int no7;
    int no8;
    int no9;

    no1 = int.Parse(txt1.Text);
    no2 = int.Parse(txt2.Text);
    no3 = int.Parse(txt3.Text);
    no4 = int.Parse(txt4.Text);
    no5 = int.Parse(txt5.Text);
    no6 = int.Parse(txt6.Text);
    no7 = int.Parse(txt7.Text);
    no8 = int.Parse(txt8.Text);
    no9 = int.Parse(txt9.Text);


    int[] a = new int[] {no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8,no9 };

    Array.Sort(a);

    foreach (var str in a)
    {
          MessageBox.Show(str.ToString()); //display in MessageBox, but i want to display back to 9 different textbox.
    }
```

I can display the result in MessageBox. but I can't display the result back to 9 different textbox. 
How can i find the solution?
Thank you 
This is the output http://i.gyazo.com/a91f7ffef1d6d1fa7815890464df3082.png

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/7dc6630ca4d752ed5ffc241f5cc5d1ae.png

Comment: Where are you trying to display that data that is not working?

Comment: @Dylan button1 is auto generate number, button2 is sort list ACS. I have 9 textbox together

Answer (score 0):

```
txt1.Text = a[0];
txt2.Text = a[1];
txt3.Text = a[2];
txt4.Text = a[3];
txt5.Text = a[4];
txt6.Text = a[5];
txt7.Text = a[6];
txt8.Text = a[7];
txt9.Text = a[8];
```

This should do the job, if I understood you correctly.